# magit: how do I turn off the -S (--gpg-sign) argument when committing?

Tags: magit

I forgot my GPG key at home and want to check in the code until I am home and can amend/resign the commits. Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to disable the `--gpg-sign=` argument in the `magit` commit popup, which is preventing me from committing.

I took a look in the manual and it says you can toggle these on and off, but doesn't specify how one toggles them.

Cheers!

**Edit:** In my magit popup the option appears as `-S` not `=S`. In the past I know that I could do just `=S` to disable it. I can't figure out how to do it with it now being prefixed with `-`.

Comment: Where in the manual is this toggling discussed?

Comment: https://magit.vc/manual/magit-popup/Usage.html

Comment: Oh yes, that's the magit-popup manual.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there was a bug and that has been fixed so this isn't relevant anymore.

Comment: I'd vote to keep it for a while still, because I hit this bug the day after the fix was released, and I would've lost many hours chasing this if this question was deleted (as per @tarsius's original suggestion).

Comment: Yeah. Lets keep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a bug and I have fixed it.

<del>I suggest you delete your question because it is no longer relevant.</del> Then again not everyone updates when encountering an issue.

Comment: I do have an updated magit, because I remember being able to turn it off with `=S` in the past. I no longer have that, and it only appears as `-S` and I can't seem to turn that off. Do you happen to know which section of the Transient documentation talks about disabling non-boolean arguments?

Comment: Ah. That's a bug then. I'll look into it tomorrow.

Comment: I can't delete it, sadly. But I did mark your answer as having answered it.